# How do I program a leader board in python?

Tags: python

I need to create a leader board in python in which the code would write the username and then the player's score on the same line in a txt file, then sort the file so the user with the highest score would be at the top and then the person with the next highest score etc. If the same user were to play the game again and get a higher score it would replace their previous score too if their score is higher than their last.

Comment: Please post what you've come up with so far.

Comment: I have nothing.

Comment: Basically, it will be useful for you to divide the code into two parts: (1) a relevant data structure for the data (like list or dictionary) (2) a procedure that prints the data structure in the desired order to a text file.

Comment: @Yanirmr I think I should start with figuring out how to write in between lines in a file, any advice on that?

Comment: If you have nothing, you should start doing something and then, if you run into a specific problem, post a question here. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @16mataylor  - I think that the better approach is to read the text file into python data structure and overwrite the file with the new data, Good luck !

Comment: @Yanirmr thank you! This is good advice, I think I know where to start now using that and your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify the data structure in which users' names and scores are stored. Suppose this is a nested list as follows:

```
scores = [["John", 1], ["Alex", 3], ["Ben", 2]]
```

Now, you need to sort this list by the second element of every nested list. You can do that in some ways, one of them is:

```
sorted_scores = scores.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Then, you can write this list, line by line:

```
with open('sorted_scores.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in sorted_scores :
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```